# Android deep link intent doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-deep-link

I have an app that listens for a deeplinks starting with `example://` The app can be launched by scanning a QR code containing a deeplink.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

I am using the code above. It works exactly as expected on Samsung hardware. My other test device is a Google Pixel 5a. When using the google default camera with my app installed, The camera sees a deeplink starting with `example://` my app is not part of the "open with" list that appears.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this is a bug specific to the Pixel camera app. The app is treating all `example://` links as though the destination is a web browser, even though `http://` or `https://` is not included

Comment: any solution on the problem?